# Increasing the timeout for .ashx

Tags: c#, ashx

Simple question: 
I need to increase the timeout for an ashx.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could just increae the server timeout:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Server.ScriptTimeout = 3600;
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }
```

Comment: Will that really work? Doesn't it override the script timeout for all pages and also the setting in web.config?